# calling SSRS report from PHP/URL with parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to call a Sql Reporting Services report from PHP using a url with parameters.  I read that it is possible to do this, however I have had no luck at this point getting it to work. The Host is "ccf08db64" and the reportserver is called just that "ReportServer". The folder where this report is under is "HrAppsApplication" and the report itself is named "MainReport".  I was told that all I had to do is simply add &parametername=parametervalue  to the url and it should work, however it doesnt display anything for me.  The link that I tried was:
http://ccf08db64/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fHRAppsApplication%2fMainReport&ThisContactId=7767

what am I missing?  if anyone has experience with calling a ssrs report via url with parameters, please fill me in... I would greatly appreciate any help you can lend me!
thanks all :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the URL you actually want is:

```
http://ccf08db64/reportserver?%2fHRAppsApplication%2fMainReport&ThisContactId=7767
```

This format works on my SSRS 2008 install, though of course with different server name, path and parameters.

If this doesn't work, does the URL posted in the first message actually render, even though its not using the specified parameters?

Comment: No, sorry but your link didnt work - the link that I posted in my question does work, however renders nothing.  I just get the report(blank) and I see the parameter text box waiting for a value

Comment: Are you sure that you have the name of the parameter correct?

Comment: Is the report your trying to render supposed to display nothing at all if the parameter(s) aren't supplied?  If that's not the case, it suggests there is an issue with your report in general.

Comment: @msmucker0527   yup, the name of the parameter is "ThisContactId" and the prompt is "ThisContactId" and the type is integer. Available values are none, default values are none, and advanced is set to auto-refresh.  on the properties of the report(in report manager) the parameter is set to prompt user and no prompt is entered

Comment: @NickThomson No, it should not render anything without a parameter value.  The report requires a ContactId to produce any data

Comment: It's not rendering because the value is not being passed correctly, make sure the name of the parameter you're using in the URL matches the name of the parameter in the Properties > Parameters options on the report server

Comment: @msmucker0527 - sorry, thats not it - It is typed exactly the same, caps and all - I wish it was as simple as that, but through all of this I did read somewhere that it is case sensative

Comment: @RickKnierim let us know when you figure out the issue

Answer (score 1):

https://**ServerName**/ReportServer/Pages/Report.aspx?**ReportPath**&**ParametersWithValues**&rs:Command=Render

This is the format I'm using, though it is for a 2005 server

Also check out this article: 
http://techpunch.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/sql-server-reporting-services-url-parameters-in-sharepoint-integrated-mode/

Though it is geared towards Sharepoint, the URLs should be the same.  It looks like the main thing you are missing is the `rs:Command=Render`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but that is what I tried already.  I wish it was that simple... actually from what i've read it should be, but isnt.

Comment: Have you tried with `&rs:Command=Render` appended to the end?

Comment: I also read that I need to access the report from the report server, not the report manager - but it seems that when I enter that url for the server, it is forwarding me to the report manager

Comment: You've got a strange problem if your reportserver site is redirecting you to Report Manager (/reports). Is SSRS working at all?

Comment: I bet it's being set up to redirect non-authenticated requests to the ReportManager.

Answer (score 1):

A distinction that is not always obvious to the uninitiated - the Report Manager and Report Server URLs have different folder paths.

Very often set to;

- http(s)://ServerName/Reports - the path that users are familiar with
- http(s)://ServerName/**ReportServer** - this is the one to append the query string to

If you append your query string to the first one, will generally redirect you to the home page as described above.